# Web components and JS DOM Elements with a placeholder

Tags: javascript, web, polymer, web-component

Lately, everyone is jumping on the Web component train for framework-agnostic UI Elements.
While I am doing my reading on this, It looks a native way to write custom elements by the browser. But I have a question like. how different it is to js way of extending div(placeholders) to enhance and give some functionality we need.

For Ex:
If I want a table component
Web Component: `<my-table></my-table>` ---- Corresponding code in JS --- Compile to js file and use in script externally

JS Way: `<div id="my-table"></div>`---- code in JS ---- Compile to JS and use in script tag externally 
I am taking the ag-grid example to make it clear

ex: ag-grid https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/

```
<div id="myGrid" style="height: 200px; width:500px;" class="ag-theme-alpine"></div>

new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
```

What's the difference and benefits of one over the other? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first reaction was,

> What is the difference between ES5 and ES6? (unless you are still doing ES3)

There are so many differences, it is quickly going to be an Apples and Apples comparison.

Read all blogs out there, play with Custom Elements, learn.

---

**TL;DR**

- Use DOM Elements with Javascript - *Order is required (1 and 2 can be switched)*:

  1. Load JavaScript
  2. Create DOM Elements
  3. Run JavaScript
  4. Transform DOM Elements
- Use Custom Elements API: - *Order does **not** matter*:
- Create Custom DOM Elements
- Load JavaScript

---

#### Differences and Benefits

Suppose Customer wanted THREE grids on the page:

- You add 3 DIVs:
  `<div id="myGrid1" .../>`
  `<div id="myGrid2" .../>`
  `<div id="myGrid3" .../>`
- To activate them you must also add:
  `new agGrid.Grid(document.getElementById("myGird1")`
  `new agGrid.Grid(document.getElementById("myGird2")`
  `new agGrid.Grid(document.getElementById("myGird3")`
- This goes horribly wrong if the JavaScript executes **before** the DOM elements exist
  So you add an event listener:
  `window.addEventListner("onload",()=>ActivateGrids());`

Note how you had to add (some type of) global function here;
so cross your fingers no-one else is going to overwrite your precious code;

- Thinking about above implications, you decide to play it safe:

  - you rename all your IDs to something that is really unique (and really unreadable)
  - you rename all your BEM Selectors to really unique (and unreadable) names
  - React, Angular, Vue do this (partly) for you,
    but you do Native JavaScript, so have to do it by hand.
- Why doesn't it work?
  You fire F12, debug, and slam your head... you made a typo in de ID.. `grid` and `gird`
- 2 days later...
  Darn! Customer wants a 4th grid!
  Before he bugs you for a 5th, you decide to refactor your ActivateGrids function to handle any number of grids in the page

`[...document.querySelectorAll('[id*="MyuniQueIDgridComponent_KUT!"]')].forEach(...)`

### We have a component!! [Play: Queen, We are the Champions!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04854XqcfCY)

- 3 weeks later Customer has a very simple request, *You can do this in half an hour*, he says. *We want to change the background color, with an attribute on the DIV*
- You are stumped!
  Changing properties with DIV attributes!?!
  Why can't they just call the JavaScript Grid instance?!?

  *You tried to educate Customer years ago; Semantic HTML has NO Future!

  Only hire SENIOR Web Developers... but he wouldn't listen*

  What is the point with `<my-grid background=green></my-grid>`

  When you can do it the ***cool*** programmers way:

  `document.getElementById("myGird1").mySetPropperty("background","green");`

  But Customer pays your mortgage;
  so you learn about a MutationObserver, and stick it on the BODY tag.
  (*This one sentence is easily written but will take a serious effort coding!*)
- 5 months later the customer says he doesn't want to hire you anymore because adding/removing Grids in their SPA cause a Memory leak.

### Enter the Custom Elements API (aka Web Components)

All of the above is (only slightly) easier with a Framework..

**But you want to build a RE-USABLE Component, NOT an Application built *with* Components**

- So you decide to go with the Native Custom Elements API

  *You thought about using Lit or Stencil or Hybrids or Component Libray X;

  but decided against them.

  Using Native JavaScript takes only a couple extra lines of code,

  but foremost you do not want to introduce a Dependency (you recall the early jQuery days when there where dozen of alternatives and you had to scrap a $$$ project because a developer choose Mootools)*

> ***Native** JavaScript will work as long as JavaScript is supported in the Browser.*

- You design how (end)user will use your component:

  `<KCB-grid rows=3  columns=5 background=color ></KCB-grid>`
- You then program the component.
  I took the **KCB-** namespace from your Twitter handle
  This namespace (like your global function) needs to be unique **in the page**
  See code below, it is a text string, so can be created dynamically!
  `<KCB-Grid-Customer rows=3  columns=5 background=color ></KCB-grid-Customer>`
- Which works in any modern Browser
  There is a polyfill for IE11; but frankly, avoid IE11.
  You stopped supporting IE9 years ago. There is a moment in time to stop supporting IE11, that moment is now.. [even Microsoft said so over a year ago](https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-security-chief-ie-is-not-a-browser-so-stop-using-it-as-your-default/)
- Works with all Frameworks and Libraries
  (except in React you need to do extra work..
  because Facebook still tries to force their 'standard' onto the rest of the world )
  https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/libraries/react/results/results.html
- There are no `onload` issues, it doesn't matter if elements are declared before or after script. Custom Elements auto upgrade.
- you can do `.innerHTML = "<KCB-Grid></KCB-Grid>"` at any time.
  Customer wanted that also,
  but hired another programmer to do it with the Custom Element below
- No CSS Selector uniqueness issues... and likely not do BEM at all
- `rows` and `columns` can be changed at any time
  Run the code snippet, click the grids

```html
<template id="KCB-GRID">
  <!-- use TEMPLATES! don't mess with JSX, CSSinJS or HTML in textstrings! -->
  <style>
    #grid { /* no BEM, no forced unique IDs or style names */
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
      grid-auto-rows:        minmax(min-content, max-content);
      gap: .2em;
    }
    #grid div {
      background: var(--background);
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  <div id=grid></div>
</template>

<KCB-Grid columns=5 rows=3 background=#FF9933></kcb-grid>
<KCB-Grid columns=3 rows=3 background=white  ></kcb-grid>
<KCB-Grid columns=4 rows=3 background=#138808></kcb-grid>

<script>
  customElements.define('kcb-grid', class extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return [ "columns", "rows" ] // only these can be changed at any time
    }
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
             .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
      this.grid = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#grid");
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      const random = (x, y) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (y + 1 - x) + x);
      this.setProperty("background");
      this.grid.onclick = () => {
                this.setAttribute("columns", random(2, 6));
                this.setAttribute("rows",    random(2, 4));
      }
    }
    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
      let columns = this.setProperty("columns");
      let rows =    this.setProperty("rows"   );
      this.grid.innerHTML = "<div>Hello World!</div>".repeat(columns * rows);
    }
    setProperty(name, value = this.getAttribute(name)) {
      this.grid.style.setProperty("--" + name, value);
      return value;
    }
    disconnectedCallback() {} //clean memory, remove listeners, etc.
  });
</script>
```

Cue Tom Lehrer's **Elements** song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcS3NOQnsQM

### And there is more to Custom Elements

- [`<slot></slot>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot)
- [shadowParts `::part`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part)
- [Constructable StyleSheets](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/constructable-stylesheets)
- Extending HTML elements so a single tag `<img is=flag-india>` [displays a SVG flag](https://flagmeister.github.io)
- ...
- ...

Comment: Excellent @Danny. What an explanation. A big Thanks to you